# joining tables in mysql while one of them is not reachable

Tags: mysql

I wrote a query that join 3 tables :

```
SELECT `notification`.`nid`, `notification`.`type`, `notification`.`read`, `notification`.`time`, `user`.`pro_img`, `user`.`fname` ,`user`.`lname`, `user`.`username`, `accommodation`.`aid`, `accommodation`.`title`, `accommodation`.`home_img`
 FROM `notification` RIGHT OUTER JOIN `user` ON `notification`.`rid`=`user`.`id` RIGHT OUTER JOIN `accommodation` ON `notification`.`acco_id`=`accommodation`.`aid`
 WHERE `notification`.`uid`=$uid ORDER BY `notification`.`time` DESC;
```

i want to have result while `notification`.`acco_id`= `accommodation`.`aid` is not found so empty columns is ok but i want rows

Comment: Hi, your database structure?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is combining a few things that don't go along. The `right joins` you are using will preserve anything that's in the right side tables, in your case `user` and `accomodation`, but using two of them with the same left side will make this useless. You also have a condition in your `where` involving the left side of the `joins`, and this also will make the `right joins` pointless.

Assuming you want all the `notifications`, regardless of them being matched with `users` and `accomodations` or not, you only need to change from `right` to `left joins`.

```
SELECT  notification.nid,
        notification.type,
        notification.read,
        notification.time,
        user.pro_img,
        user.fname,
        user.lname,
        user.username,
        accommodation.aid,
        accommodation.title,
        accommodation.home_img
FROM    notification
LEFT OUTER JOIN
        user
ON      notification.rid = user.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
        accommodation
ON      notification.acco_id = accommodation.aid
WHERE   notification.uid = $uid
ORDER BY notification.time DESC
```

This will preserve all the rows in `notification`, and will match them with `null` values when there are no matching rows on the other table(s).